# File cache for large files in perl

Tags: perl, file, caching, download

I am looking for a cache library in Perl. But the ones I found so far like Cache::Cache and CHI all seem to assume you want to read the file into a data structure in Perl. I am only interested to caching the files to disk without ever reading the file content into Perl.

The files I am dealing with are around 200 MB and will be downloaded from the net. I want a size limit of the cache and an expiry time for the cached files.

Any suggestions ?

**Edit: As I did not find any ready library for this I have implemented it myself now. But if anyone can point to one anyway it would of course be interesting.**

Comment: why would you want to cache data that you're not using?

Comment: I use it obviously, but not as perl data structures.

Comment: Simply don't understand. You want cache something FROM perl, but not a perl data structure. So HOW want cache it from the perl? Because when you will serving the file with perl, you WILL read the file. If not, that has nothing with perl, so check some standalone caching daemon or soo... Or I'm missed something?

Comment: @jm666 The files will just be downloaded and executed, not read. So yes it could be done outside of perl, but based on the current setup it would be very convenient to use a perl library if it existed. I also need platform independence.

Answer (score 1):

Solve the problem with one layer of indirection. Store references to files, not the files themselves, in the cache. How exactly a reference looks like depends on your use case.

Comment: Unsure if this would help so much, as I guess it would not directly make use of size limit of the cache. And how should I have the files deleted when the reference is deleted ?

Answer (score -2):

Try the Cache::File module from CPAN

Comment: As I understand this (just as Cache::Cache) also requires the data to be read into a variable first.